# Mail sent from local Postfix marked as "possible phishing" in Outlook

Tags: exchange, postfix

Sorry for the newbie question--this is not my area of expertise by a long shot. I work at a small development shop and we finally got around to doing code reviews. (Yay!) I set up an instance of Review Board -- an open-source code review tool -- on one of our local servers but it doesn't seem to like talking to our hosted Exchange server to send notification emails.

I decided to just install Postfix on that same box and send mail from localhost, which is working much more reliably, but Outlook disables all links in the email announcements and marks it as possible phishing. What is making these emails look suspicious and what can I change?

Would the best thing be to figure out how to relay to Exchange from Postfix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since Outlook's filtering policies don't reveal why something is caught; you're going to have to look for "normal" spam signs. The best way to relay from Postfix to Exchange is through normal old SMTP, confirming to Internet configuration norms.